# I'm having issues getting info from a quiz I made with PHP (a series of sets of ten sets of four radio buttons) to submit to the PHP test results page

Tags: php

/*I can't get the submit button to do anything whatsoever no matter where I put the various elements. I've tried moving the button outside the form, as well as creating a separate form for the button itself. I've also tried removing the reset quiz button all together.*/

```
   <?php
   $rightanswer = isset($_POST['rightanswer']);
   //$wronganswer = isset($_POST['wronganswer']);
   
   
   
   ?>
   
   
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html>
   <head>
       
   <title>PHP Quiz</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizstyles.css"/>
       
       
   </head>
   <body>
    <form action="results.php">   
   <h1>PHP Quiz</h1>
       </br></br>
   <div id = "questions">
   
   <h2>Question 1</h2>
   
   <p>PHP files have a default extention of:</p>
   <form value = "1">
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="a" />A .php<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B .html<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C .xml<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D .ph<br />
   </form>
   
   <h2>Question 2</h2>
   
   <p>What is the correct way to add a comment in PHP?</p>
   <form value = "2">
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="a" />A //<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B !//!<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C #comment<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D *//*<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 3</h2>
   
   <p>PHP requires which of these things in order to run?</p>
   <form value = "3">
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="a" />A Microsoft Word<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B Ubuntu Linux<br />
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="c" />C A web server<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D League of Legends<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 4</h2>
   
   <p>Which of the following is true about PHP?</p>
   <form value = "4">
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="a" />A It is a client side language<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B It travels in packs <br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C It was created in 2019<br />
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="d" />D It is a server side language which requires a web server to run<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 5</h2>
   
   <p>Which of the following is a program which would allow PHP to run?</p>
   <form value = "5">
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="a" />A XAMPP<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B Zoom<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C WAMPP<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D Both A and C<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 6</h2>
   
   <p>Which of the Following is NOT true about PHP?</p>
   <form value = "6">
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="a" />A It will only run with XAMPP<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B It is a server side programming language<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C It can be run within html code<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D It can run with XAMPP WAMPP or MAMPP<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 7</h2>
   
   <p>Choose the correct way to add a multi line comment in PHP</p>
   <form value = "7">
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="a" />A .php_comment<br />
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="b" />B /**/<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C #comment#<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D ()comment() <br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 8</h2>
   
   <p>What symbols do you start and end PHP code with?</p>
   <form value = "8">
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="a" />A >?<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B #$$#<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C $!!$<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D ;**;<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 9</h2>
   
   <p>Which of the following is NOT a type of PHP loop?</p>
   <form value = "9">
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="a" />A while<br />
       
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="b" />B foreach.html<br />
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="c" />C during<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D dowhile<br />
   </form>
   <h2>Question 10</h2>
   
   <p>What XAMPP service is required to run PHP?</p>
   <form value = "10">
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="a" />A MySQL<br />
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="b" />B Apache<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="c" />C Tomcat<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer" value="d" />D Mercury<br />
   </form>
   
       </div>
           <div id="buttons">
       <label>&nbsp</label>
               </br>
          <form action = "index.html">
       <input type="submit" value="Reset Quiz"></br>
       </form></br>    
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz"></br>    
   </div> 
   </form>
       
       
       
   </body>
   
   </html>
```

The below is the results page that is meant to display the test score, as well as the problem(s) gotten wrong. I am unsure of whether or not this is the issue.

```
    <?php
    //$wronganswer = isset($_POST['wronganswer']);
    $rightanswer = isset($_POST['rightanswer']);
    
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
        
    <title>PHP Quiz Results</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizstyles.css"/>
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Quiz Results:</h1></br>
        <h2>Your Score (out of 10) is: <?php echo $totalscore . "/10"?></h2></br>
        <h2>Incorrect Questions:</h2></br>
    
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['wronganswer'])) {
        echo "1" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "2" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
           /* else {
        echo "3" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "4" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "5" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "6" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "7" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "8" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "9" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }
            else {
        echo "10" ."</br>". "The correct answer is" . $rightanswer;
        }*/
           
    ?>
    
    
        
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: That `Submit quiz` element needs to be inside a `form` element, and also, it will only submit the values for input elements inside the same form, so the other form elements (`<form value=...`) will be ignored. I'd suggest you put all the inputs in the one `form` element, and give each of them unique names, eg `rightanswer-1` for the first question. Then you can identify them in the submission handling code.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work at all. What you need here is one form. Don't name all of the radio buttons with `rightanswer` and `wronganswer`. Just name them with the name of the question, and figure out if the right answer was selected on the `results.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

Your very first mistake - You have used one form inside another form,So I will suggest you to use single form for all inputs:

```
   <form action="results.php">   
   <h1>PHP Quiz</h1>
       </br></br>
   <div id = "questions">
   
   <h2>Question 1</h2>
   
   <p>PHP files have a default extention of:</p>
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer1" value="a" />A .php<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer1" value="b" />B .html<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer1" value="c" />C .xml<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer1" value="d" />D .ph<br />
   ......
    .......
   <h2>Question 10</h2>
   
   <p>What XAMPP service is required to run PHP?</p>
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer10" value="a" />A MySQL<br />
   <input type="radio" name="rightanswer10" value="b" />B Apache<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer10" value="c" />C Tomcat<br />
   <input type="radio" name="wronganswer10" value="d" />D Mercury<br />

   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz"></br>    
   </div> 
   </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! I did try that before, and the program wouldn't let me click one radio button for each question, it would remove the indicator from the previously clicked radio button and move it further down the list of questions. For example, when I click one of the question 3 radio buttons, the radio button I clicked for question 2 is deselected.

Comment: You have to use different radio groups name like rightanswer1 for first group/question, rightanswer2 for second and so on..and also use same name for same group eg. For question1 give name answer1 to 4 radios but can use different id.@wno7736